# which language / tool to use

Tags: c#, java

Here's the situation:

I need to develop a desktop tool that will take in an input from Oracle (text) and it's output is a print of a layout generated by that tool.

The tool needs to be fast and able to print easily and not much extra software required on client PC's which ALL run Windows.

Now i've studied Java, PHP in the past however I don't want to use PHP for the Desktop App
and I have my doubts about Java in regards to Printing and developing the GUI.

It seems to me like with C# I can develop the GUI easier and faster, and most PC's have a lot of the tools required for the GUI in the OS (.net framework).

A tool like NetBeans helps, but more often than not the GUI design is either broken
or shoots across the screen when I make a simple change.

So now I'm thinking about starting in Visual C#, however I would like to get your 
opinion.

And from my past VERY short .NET programming experience, I can still remember that deploying over the internet is easy as well, with JAVA I've had some issues with that as well before I got it to work.

So in short:

- Windows environment
- Lot of GUI design
- Fast app that runs on client Windows PC's without much 'extra' software installing
- Easy print programming

THANK YOU!

Comment: Hopefully it seems your biased question already gives us your prefered reply, so that we can answer "C#, obviously !" :-)

Answer (score 2):

My preference would be C# or VB.NET with Windows Forms. WPF is also worth looking at, and will give you the most modern UI, but it has debatably a steeper learning curve attached.

Comment: +1: WPF is excellent, and once you're familiar with it will let you build seriously cool UI's, but the learning curve is punishing to get to that point. It's definetly worth it, but don't take it on unless you've the time to go back and re-start your UI from scratch 3 or 4 times.

Comment: 1) animation effects, theming, skinning - everything you'd expect from a modern UI
2) it's data-bound which means the UI is disconnected from all the functional code. While separation is a good thing in general, it also means a designer can easily work on UI while a coder works on functions.
3) data bindings mean that when something in your model changes - e.g. the value of a property - every bit in the UI that presents that property updates automatically. That sort of thing is hard to get right in Windows Forms.